# Why is it not possible to fetch facebook events even after app review?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

We are building an app that aggregates events from multiple Facebook pages.

With our app we got through the Facebook App Review process (with fancy screencasts and all) and they granted us the "Page Public Content Access" permission.

I tested it and I can now fetch page information from all pages.
However, the page event api (`GET /<page>/events`) always returns an empty array now

According to this [blog post](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2018/04/04/facebook-api-platform-product-changes) from Facebook about restricting access to same API's:

> apps currently accessing Events and Groups APIs will lose access today. Going forward, access to these APIs will require a formal app review

With the "formal app review" are they not talking about the "Page Public Content Access" permission that you need to request?

I am aware there are multiple questions about accessing page events, but all of them seem about getting the Page Public Content Access permission, which we have received from Facebook.